# What does it mean to populate something with a scan?

Tags: meaning

In an exercise I came across this:

> In this case, the solution is to enable the Source cache, and populate
>   it with a Scan before the first round of translation commences.

What do they mean by populating the enabled source cache with a scan?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Try “with the results of a scan”

Comment: I don't think this can be definitively answered without more context. Is this talking about optical character recognition (OCR) used to scan in a book in one language before translating it into a different language? This *seems* likely, but it's not clear.

Comment: The person (I presume a teacher) who assigned the exercise to you is likely to be in a much better position to clarify what the exercise requires than somebody on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the data is read into a cache, before being translated. The verb "populate" is used to mean "fill".

The Oxford dictionary entry for [**populate**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/populate) has these examples for:

**1.3 *Computing***

> In order to make things a bit more interesting, let's populate our
>   table with some values.
>
> You can then populate tables with text and updatable fields.